# Who owns the Graphic Design chatroom?

Tags: support, chat

The [Graphic Design room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/188/graphic-design) doesn't seem to have an owner:

[image: Screenshot of room info page showing the lack of a room owner]

Of course, the low activity in the room now means that it's fine without an owner, but I think it would be a good idea to give somebody the powers to conduct janitorial works and the like without having to call in mods, when the room activity picks up.

Comment: is there a subtle "gimme gimme" in there?

Comment: @MarcGravell Wh.. what? Eh, no :P I deny that I actively *seek* to be the owner there

Comment: @Marc Lol...! :)

Comment: It is *my* room, but I prefer to stay anonymous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mods (*any* mod on *any* SE site at all) can set themselves as owner and then add others to the role.

Put a mod attention flag on a message asking for giving ownership to somebody.